# Вопрос по устройству файловой системы в Android

Tags: android, файловая-система

Итак, пытаясь разработать приложение в котором предусмотрена навигация по файлам я решил сделать такую фичу, суть ее в том, что юзер не может лазить по всем папкам в системе, а только по папкам sd карты и памяти телефона.

Узнал что таковыми папками являются `/storage/emulated/0/` и `/storage/extSdcard/`. Все работало хорошо, пока я не запустил приложение на телефоне друга. Оказалось так, что у него нет папки `/storage/emulated/0/`, и все файлы хранятся в `/storage/sdcard/`.

У меня на телефоне версия `Android 5.1`, у него `6.1` и я подумал, что возможно, с выходом новой системы изменилось структура файловой системы Android. Но каково было мое удивление, когда я попросил телефон у своего другого друга с `Android 6.0`, т.к. папка `/storage/emulated/0`/ у него была, но ни папки `/storage/extSdcard/` ни просто `/storage/sdcard/` не было. И после этого я задумался. А как мне вообще узнать есть ли у телефона sd-карта. И как узнать все таки пути к карте и к внутреннему хранилищу телефона.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить путь:

- к встроенной памяти:

  ```
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  ```
- к карте памяти:

  ```
  ArrayList<MountDevice> storages = StorageHelper.getInstance()
      .getRemovableMountedDevices();

  if (storages.size() != 0) {
      // Перебираем карты памяти в цикле.
      // Путь к корню получаем через storages.get(i).getPath().
  }
  ```

  Подробнее описано в статье «[Получение пути к карте памяти SD Card на Android](https://habrahabr.ru/post/254813/)».

Comment: @Arhad, спасибо за редактирование

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть метод который проверяет есть ли sd карта

```
private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {  
 String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {  
   return true;  
  }  
  return false;  
}
```

Также обрати внимание на то что существует 2 типа внешнего хранилища:

- Primary External Storage: встроенное внешнее хранилище которое "доступно пользователем при подключении USB кабеля и монтирования его на компьютер". Например: Nexus 5 32GB.
- Secondary External Storage: Извлекаемое хранилище. Например: SD карта